ChangeNotifier with ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments
I have a class that inherits from ChangeNotifier and does simple list control. This class works very well if I don't call ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments before it, but when calling ModalRoute it simply stops working.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListController extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List _list = [];
  int _changedIndex = 0;
  String _command = "";

  void addAll(List list) {
    _command = "addAll";
    _list.addAll(list);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get command{
    return _command;
  }

  void reloadGrid(){
    _command = "reload";
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clear() {
    _command = "clear";
    _list.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void add(Map<String, dynamic> item) {
    _command = "add";
    _changedIndex = 0;
    _list.insert(0,item);
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void update(int index, Map<String, dynamic> item) {
    _command = "update";
    _changedIndex = index;
    _list[index] = item;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeAt(int index) {
    _command = "removeAt";
    _changedIndex = index;
    _list.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List get list{
    return [..._list];
  }

  int get changedIndex{
    return _changedIndex;
  }


}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final arguments =
        ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as List<Object?>;
    final ListController detailController = ListController();
...
body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: DetailComponent(columns: columns, controller: detailController),
      ),

I expected it to work fine even calling ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments

you need to pass a List of object as route arguments while visiting this route, it would be easier for us if you can include how you are coming to this page/route

Why don't you access your controller using a state management solution or a locator like get_it?
